# Update Salesforce Object from Marketing Cloud Automation Studio Using Script

Tags: javascript, salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud, ssjs

I would like to update a record in the Sales Cloud object using Script in Automation Studio in Marketing Cloud.

I found the code: https://gist.github.com/katydorjee/818912244f95c49c0bf52c175d00cfe8. I've tried to apply it to my case, but it errors "ERROR:  A runtime error occurred while the SSJS Activity executed the SSJS script. Please review the SSJS activity to ensure that errors are handled properly."

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1.1.1");

var sfUpdateString;
var targetDE = DataExtension.Init('xxx').Rows.Retrieve();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < targetDE.length; i++) 
  {
    var Field1 = targetDE[i].AccountID;
    var Field2 = targetDE[i].Gender;

sfUpdateString = '';
sfUpdateString = '%'+'%[SET @uso = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Account","'+Field1+'"';
sfUpdateString += ',"Gender__c","'+Field2+'")]%'+'%';
Platform.Function.TreatAsContent(sfUpdateString);
Write(Platform.Variable.GetValue("@uso"));
  }
</script>
```

**Data Extension:**
|AccountID           | Gender         |
| ------------------ | -------------- |
| 0015g00000FwcXXXXX | Female         |

**Account (Salesforce Object):**

Id = 0015g00000FwcXXXXX

Name = Mr. A

Gender__c(picklist field) = ' ' (I would like to update this field to be "Female")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change "Platform.Load("core","1.1.1");" to "Platform.Load("core","1");" and it works well now.